# How to show loading indicator in simple way?

Tags: flutter

I'm coding `await user?.reload();//here` to reload `UserClass ' and during reloading, want to display indicator.

I learned Using `FutureProvider-when() method` from river_pod or 'FutureBuilder-snapshot` to implement this indicator.

Is these resolve is general or wonder there is more simple way to implement indicator display like this case ?

thanks for your helpful comment.

```dart
void currentUserNotNull(User? user, ref) async {
  try {
    var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    await user?.reload();//here
    ref.read(authLoadingProvider.notifier).update((state) => false);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
//
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iam using this method to loading, you can also use flutter spinners also

Try this

showLoaderDialog(BuildContext context){
AlertDialog alert=AlertDialog(
content: new Row(
children: [
CircularProgressIndicator(),
Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7),child:Text("Loading..." )),
],),
);
showDialog(barrierDismissible: false,
context:context,
builder:(BuildContext context){
return alert;
},
);
}

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this using `flutter_easyloading package` like

```
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';
void currentUserNotNull(User? user, ref) async {
  try {
    EasyLoading.show(maskType: EasyLoadingMaskType.black, status: "Loading...");
    var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    await user?.reload();//here
    EasyLoading.dismiss();
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
//
  }
}
```

but still wonder I should do this or not...